# Check for the value of x for function f is ill conditioned

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I have two examples: 
$$ i) \ f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} $$ 
$$ ii) \ f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x $$

I must check the value of x for which the calculation of the values ​​of the function $ f $ is ill conditioned. 
I solved it, but I don't know whether it is well.

$ i) $ Function is ill-conditioned for $ x = 1 \vee x=-1 $  
$ ii) $ Function hasn't ill-conditioned.

Comment: In the first one, what is $f(2)$?

Comment: @GitGud Should we consider only interval $ [-1,1] $, because $ 1-x^2 \ge 0 $. I solved this example like : $ cond(x)=\frac{x\cdot f'(x)}{f(x)} = -\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $ And next step is consider function zeros. My solution is well?

Comment: @GitGud second example is good?

Comment: In the first one $[-1,1]$ is correct. The second one is correct too.

Comment: @GitGud How you check second case so quickly? How is yours method?

Comment: You need to make sure that $x^2+1\ge 0$ because of the square root, but $x^2+1\ge x^2\ge 0$ for all real numbers  .$x$